# Is it possible to receive ajax response without PHP echo

Tags: php, ajax

php

```
<?php echo "registered successfully" ?>
```

Js

```
 success : function (response) {
                    alert(response); 
    }
```

The above could would print hello upon success and I want to redirect the user only if a condition is true.
I could use `if (response == registered successfully) {then redirect}`

But what if I don't want to echo anything and just redirect the user, could i use something like `return "yes";` and use that in success function's if condition. Is there something else I can use instead of echo ?

Comment: As long as you don't return a http status of `200` when something goes wrong, you can redirect in the `success` function.

Comment: Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: @JayBlanchard It's kinda funny that that article itself is outdated - some of the problems with `alert` have since been solved, like "This will drive you crazy once you put your alert code accidentally in a loop." - browsers now let you suppress further dialogs on a page.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can return an empty string. In the JavaScript side, check that `response.status` is `200` (indicating a successful response).

You could also have PHP return a [`204 No Content` response](http://php.net/http-response-code):

```
http_response_code(204)
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually just kill or echo `echo ("1");` when the code executed  successfully on my ajax handler page.

```
success : function (response) {
      if (repsonse.trim() == "1"){
        alert(response); 
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just redirect with js after the ajax function, if you don't need to get anything from php

```
$.ajax({...});
window.location.replace(anyurl);
```